# Symbolic differentiation of a function with respect to another symbolic function using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I updated my Python3 and sympy and all of a sudden my code does not work anymore. I try the following code:

```
    import sympy as sym
    x, y, z= sym.symbols('x[0], x[1], x[2]')
    theta = sym.atan2(y,x)
    t = theta + pi
    r_1 =  0.0124*sym.cos(t)+0.0414*sym.sin(2*t)
    f = (r_1)*sym.cos(t)
    diff_f = sym.diff(f,theta)
```

When I run it I receive the following error:

```
Can't calculate derivative wrt atan2(x[1], x[0])
```

Now this used to work with the old version ( I don't recall exactly which version it was). But right now I am trying this with the latest versions of Python and sympy and I get this error. I would really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the expression for a symbol and then differentiate wrt that:

```
In [3]: a = Symbol('a')                                                                                                                        

In [4]: f.subs(theta, a).diff(a).subs(a, theta)                                                                                                
Out[4]: 
-0.0828⋅x[0]⋅cos(2⋅atan2(x[1], x[0])) 
──────────────────────────────────────
             _______________          
            ╱     2       2           
          ╲╱  x[0]  + x[1]
```